# Owl carousel: not pulling data-src value as background image in CSS for Vimeo videos

Tags: jquery, css, attributes, background-image, owl-carousel

I'm using Owl Carousel to display both YouTube and Vimeo videos, and the YouTube videos are displaying their corresponding thumbnail images, but the Vimeo videos aren't. I looked into the source and noticed that Owl's js seems to be pulling in the URL for the image in a data-src attribute. For the YouTube videos, it's taking the data-src value and applying it as a background image (via css) for the div. For the Vimeo videos, it's pulling in the data-src, but not applying it to the div's css. Here's a snippet of the code as an example:

```
<div class="owl-item cloned" data-video="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9RBOvGwQ4To" style="width: 580px; margin-right: 10px;">
  <div class="item-video" data-merge="2">
    <div class="owl-video-wrapper">
      <a class="owl-video" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9RBOvGwQ4To" style="display: none;"></a>
      <div class="owl-video-play-icon"></div>
      <div class="owl-video-tn owl-lazy" data-src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/9RBOvGwQ4To/hqdefault.jpg" style="background-image: url("http://img.youtube.com/vi/9RBOvGwQ4To/hqdefault.jpg"); opacity: 1;"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="owl-item active center" data-video="https://player.vimeo.com/video/143757230" style="width: 580px; margin-right: 10px;">
  <div class="item-video" data-merge="2">
    <div class="owl-video-wrapper">
      <a class="owl-video" href="https://player.vimeo.com/video/143757230" style="display: none;"></a>
      <div class="owl-video-play-icon"></div>
      <div class="owl-video-tn owl-lazy" data-src="https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/541423305_640.jpg"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The top .owl-item is a YouTube video, and the bottom is a Vimeo video. You'll see the difference in the .owl-video-tn divs.

I've tried a couple of jQuery workarounds that don't seem to be working. (Maybe I'm doing something wrong?) Here's what I've tried so far:

```
if ($("div[data-src*='vimeocdn']")) {
    var imageUrl = $(".owl-video-tn").attr("data-src")
    $('.owl-video-tn').css('background-image', 'url(' + imageUrl + ')':'background-repeat', 'no-repeat':'background-position','left top');
}
```

---

```
$("div[data-src*='vimeocdn']").each(function () {
  var imageUrl = $(".owl-video-tn").attr("data-src")
  $(this).css('background-image', 'url(' + imageUrl + ')':'background-repeat', 'no-repeat':'background-position','left top');
});
```

---

```
$("div[data-src*='vimeocdn']").each(function () {
  var $img = $("div[data-src*='vimeocdn']");
  $(this).css('background-image', 'url('+ $img +')':'background-repeat', 'no-repeat':'background-position','left top');
});
```

Thoughts? Suggestions? Corrections on my jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, I didn't need a jQuery workaround after all. I had the "lazyLoad" option enabled, and disabling it fixed my problem.